# How can I distinguish between two windows VS2008 with branches?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, branch

We have got two branches - trunk and release. We work with just one generally. But we work with two branches some time. Branches open in two windows VS2008. They look the same. They differ only in the filepath. What can I do to make them clearly look different?

Comment: This is a real problem and I'm desperately looking for a solution.

Comment: @Kabeer Not sure if it helps you but you may be interested in my answer posted just now. Feel free to flag this comment as obsolete once you've seen it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the solution in properties explorer so that the window title is different.

This will rename the .sln file, but the content will be the same. Just rename it back to its original title before you reintegrate.

This will give you the effect of having windows with two different names open while working on the branch and trunk at the same time.

**Edit:**

Another alternative would be creating different solution files for the branches with different titles, linking in the same projects, but then you need to keep them synced. Depending on how often you add/remove projects this might be a pain.

Comment: It's not very convenient. It will have to do with each merge. I want add solution folder named !Release.

Comment: You could create different solution files for the branches with different titles, linking in the same projects, but then you need to keep them synced. Depending on how often you add/remove projects this might be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 (but unfortunately, it appears, at least this one not for 2008), there exists an extension named [Rename Visual Studio Window Title](http://erwinmayer.com/labs/visual-studio-2010-extension-rename-visual-studio-window-title/) which allows you to put a portion of, or quite possibly all of, the path to the solution file into the Visual Studio window title.

I'm using it with VS2010 and for all I can tell, it works great.

Maybe if you ask really nicely, the author can be persuaded to make a version that works with VS2008 as well.